# Find and click element based on @onclick w/ Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find a element using Selenium in Python that has the html like this:

```
<td class="td1" onclick="window.location.href = 'work_area.php?SID';">Work area</td>
```

Contained in a simple `<tr></tr>` tag.

I have tried using

```
work_area = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td[contains(@onclick, "work_area.php?SID"]')
```

and using an absolute xpath

```
work_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td")
```

My buttons structure:

```
+---------------------+
|       Menu          |
+---------------------+
|     Work Area       |
+---------------------+
|     Details         |
+---------------------+
```

I am using Python 3.6, and Selenium is up to date, any suggestions?
I have also tried different suggestions that I could find on stackoverflow but nothing helped.

Comment: *"I have also tried all the versions"*... which exactly?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fpsesdyc Here, these are "all the versions" that were suggested or refered to similar problems, that I could provide links for*

Comment: No, I mean your implementation. What else you've tried instead of just locate element? Share the code

Comment: I have only tried using Selenium, I know about BeatifulSoup and other modules. I will edit :)

Comment: Did you try Explicit/Implicit wait? Did you check whether element is located inside an iframe?

Comment: yes, I have tried using Explicit/Implicit wait but they didn't seem to work, the website is build pretty bad and a lot of things are unclear in their code, thats why I couldn't figure it out. And no, it's not located inside an iframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use locators below:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td[onclick*='work_area']")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[.='Work area']")
```

You code below wasn't correct, locator is xpath and you use css selector:

> ```
> work_area = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td[contains(@onclick,"work_area.php?SID"]')
> ```