# How to click through onclick event with in a table through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am automating a function where the user needs to click on the link highlighted in the below link.

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNIp7.jpg)

I tried a contains on the xpath which is `//*[@id="lc"]`, and an onclick option from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52191015/find-and-click-element-based-on-onclick-w-selenium/52191132) neither of which work and error with the element doesn't exist error.

I know I am in the right iframe, because when using the xpath with no contains the script clicks the first xpath link with no issue.

Comment: could you be more specific about what you are trying to do here?  this HTML structure if pretty complex, and obfuscated, so it's hard to figure just where that selected td is located.  if the id is not unique, then we need to find something else...is there something unique in the method that's being called in the onclick?

Comment: Please share your code between code tags and the relevant html using the snippet tool available via [edit]. Also, include the url if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the desired element as the element is a *dynamic* element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.EMROtherEpsEven>table tr>td.EMROtherEpsEven#lc[onclick*='Hemoglobin']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='EMROtherEpsEven']/table//tr/td[@class='EMROtherEpsEven' and @id='lc'][contains(@onclick, 'Hemoglobin')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I have not use Selenium with Python, but I have with java, and in Java you have to use simple quote (') instead the double quote ("), or you can just a simpler locator id=lc  without any quotes, if you're sure the ID is correct this should work.

Comment: Unfortunately the xpath is the same on all td elements, so this is why I was looking for the onclick method as then I can call out this specific link.

Comment: Oh ok, in that case I use Katalon Recorder (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid) , it is a lot better than Selenium IDE to get the right xpath.

Comment: "xpath is the same on all td elements"...are you saying that all td elements have an "id" attribute of "lc"?  that would be BAD HTML.

Answer (score 0):

i have done this in java hope you find the answer
 yes in static or in dynamic tables the id will be the same but if you try using absolute xpath 
 this are two absolute path of the table element resides each other in first row

```
/html[1]/body[1]/section[1]/section[1]/div[1]/data[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]

/html[1]/body[1]/section[1]/section[1]/div[1]/data[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]
```

This are the relative xpath of the same elements

```
//a[contains(text(),'AF17OT41603')]

//div[@id='1547533504703-0-uiGrid-000C-cell']//div[@class='ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope'][contains(text(),'AKSHAY PATIL')]
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9Ogy.png)